# My Button is Getting Cut off and not Showing all of the text in it (within a sidemenu)

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8

Image of the current Application

[image: Image of the current Application]

Attached above is an image of of my application that I am making. Currently the text in `QPushButton` is getting cut off in my sidemenu and I need the full text to be shown. Here is my code currently:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

stylesheet = """
    QWidget{
        background-color: white;
    }

    QWidget#sideMenuBackground{
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }

    QVBoxLayout#sideMenuLayout{
        background-color: grey;
    }


    QPushButton#sideMenuButton{
        text-align: left;
        border: none;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        max-width: 10em;
        font: 16px; 
        padding: 6px;
    }

    QPushButton#sideMenuButton:hover{
        font: 18px;
    }

    QLabel#today_label{
        font: 25px;
        max-width: 70px;
    }

    QLabel#todays_date_label{
        font: 11px;
        color: grey;
    }

    QPushButton#addTodoEventButton{
        border: none;
        max-width: 130px;
    }


"""




class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Public Transport Application")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 500)
        self.showMaximized()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        backgroundWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        backgroundWidget.setObjectName('sideMenuBackground')
        backgroundWidget.setFixedWidth(300)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(backgroundWidget)
        sideMenuLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        sideMenuLayout.setObjectName('sideMenuLayout')
        self.taskLayout = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()

        backgroundWidget.setLayout(sideMenuLayout)
        layout.addLayout(self.taskLayout)

        self.setSideMenu(sideMenuLayout)
        sideMenuLayout.addStretch(0)

        self.setMainLayout(self.taskLayout)

        mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        mainWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

    def setSideMenu(self, layout):
        self.AButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Account')
        self.IJUPTButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('I Just Used Public Transport')
        self.CTTOTButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Compare the Types of Transport')
        self.LSButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('License Statistics')
        self.AdminButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Admin Viewing')
        self.OPPButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Our Privacy Policy')

        sideMenuButtons = [self.AButton, self.IJUPTButton, self.CTTOTButton, self.LSButton, self.AdminButton, self.OPPButton]
        for button in sideMenuButtons:
            button.setObjectName('sideMenuButton')
            layout.addWidget(button)

        sideMenuButtons[0].pressed.connect(self.AButtonPress)
        sideMenuButtons[1].pressed.connect(self.IJUPTButtonPress)
        sideMenuButtons[2].pressed.connect(self.CTTOTButtonPress)
        sideMenuButtons[3].pressed.connect(self.LSButtonPress)
        sideMenuButtons[4].pressed.connect(self.AdminButtonPress)
        sideMenuButtons[5].pressed.connect(self.OPPButtonPress)

    def setMainLayout(self, layout):
        Accounts = self.AccountsWidget()
        IJUPT = self.IJUPTWidget()
        CTTOT = self.CTTOTWidget()
        LS = self.LSWidget()
        Admin = self.AdminWidget()
        OPP = self.OPPWidget()

        layout.addWidget(Accounts)
        layout.addWidget(IJUPT)
        layout.addWidget(CTTOT)
        layout.addWidget(LS)
        layout.addWidget(Admin)
        layout.addWidget(OPP)

    def AccountsWidget(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        # setup layout for today's widget
        return widget

    def IJUPTWidget(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        # setup layout for calendar widget
        return widget

    def CTTOTWidget(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        # setup layout for calendar widget
        return widget

    def LSWidget(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        # setup layout for calendar widget
        return widget

    def AdminWidget(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        # setup layout for calendar widget
        return widget

    def OPPWidget(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        # setup layout for calendar widget
        return widget

    def AButtonPress(self):
        self.taskLayout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def IJUPTButtonPress(self):
        self.taskLayout.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def CTTOTButtonPress(self):
        self.taskLayout.setCurrentIndex(2)

    def LSButtonPress(self):
        self.taskLayout.setCurrentIndex(3)

    def AdminButtonPress(self):
        self.taskLayout.setCurrentIndex(4)

    def OPPButtonPress(self):
        self.taskLayout.setCurrentIndex(5)




def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()

main()
```

It's highly appreciated if anyone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the line / * max-width: 10em; * / from the stylesheet

Comment: Thank you!!! That's really appreciated